# How to access the array variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, multidimensional-array, timestamp

I am trying to echo a variable inside a object array..

```
array(4) 
{ 
 [0]=> int(20) 
 [1]=> string(16) "Demo Blog Post 3" [2]=> string(753) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit" 
 [3]=> object(DateTime)#1 (3) 
  {
   ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-19 13:28:23" 
   ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
   ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Muscat" 
  } 
}
```

I want the **date** object in this array... how can I get this... ?

```
 $times = $row[3]->date;     // Returning NULL
 echo count($times);         // 1
 $times = $row[3]['date'];   // Returning CodeBreak.
```

**var_dump($row[3])**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-19 13:28:23" 
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
  ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Muscat" 
 }
```

**var_dump(get_object_vars($row[3]))**

```
array(3) 
{ 
  ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-19 13:28:23" 
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
  ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Muscat" 
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: what you are getting for var_dump($row[3]); ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Edited Question.

Comment: try `$row[3]->date` because your `$row` is a object!

Comment: Its already tried. see my question... its returning NULL

Comment: now var_dump(get_object_vars ($row[3])); and update your question.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Updated

Comment: now try to get var_dump(get_object_vars ($row[3])['date'] );

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaaaw... Its Working.. Thanks Dude.

Comment: I am posting a solution, it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) this helps you to get the properties of the given object

like this

```
var_dump(get_object_vars ($row[3])['date'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you named your array `$products`, wouldn't you get date from `$products[3]["date"]`?